# Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, vector

У меня есть вот такое объявление вектора:

```
vector::vector(size_type n, const string& val = string());
```

Честно говоря, я вообще не понимаю что тут происходит, кроме того, что я собственно объявляю вектор. Прошу, объясните, пожалуйста!

К тому же выдаёт ещё вот такую ошибку:

```
[Error] 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector' used without template arguments
```

Насколько я понимаю, нужно добавить `template <что-то>` перед функцией, но я не совсем понимаю что именно.

Спасибо всем, кто объяснит!

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Если вы не знаете, что такое шаблоны или классы, то задавайте соответствующий вопрос (найдите дубликат)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте для начала разберем, что такое шаблоны.

> Шабло́ны — средство языка C++, предназначенное для кодирования обобщённых алгоритмов, без привязки к некоторым параметрам. В C++ возможно создание **шаблонов функций** и **классов**.

Шаблон функции:

```
template <typename T>
void swap (T& x, T& y){
// тело функции
T temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
}
```

Этот шаблон принимает две [ссылки](https://ravesli.com/urok-88-ssylki/) на обобщенный тип `T` и переставляет значения под ссылками местами. То есть мы можем написать

```
int main (){
int x = 5;
int y = 12;

std::cout << "x = " << x << "\t y =" << y << endl;

double k =9.4;

double j =45.22;

std::cout << "j = " << j << "\t k =" << k << endl;
swap(x, y);
std::cout << "x = " << x << "\t y =" << y << endl;
swap(k, j);
std::cout << "j = " << j << "\t k =" << k << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Что происходит на этапе компиляции:

```
Компилятор : видит, что swap шаблонная. То есть ее можно вызывать от любых переменных с одинаковым типом, но тип не указан.

У компилятора : есть сложная система правил шаблонного вывода, которая в конечном счете подскажет ему какой тип вместо T подставить.

Компилятор : Подставит нужный тип. Вызовет функцию с нужным типом.
```

Чтобы это быстрее работало можно написать:

```
int main (){
int x = 5;
int y = 12;

swap <int>(x, y);
return 0;
}
```

Тут мы явно указываем компилятору, что хотим вызвать `void swap (int x, int y);`

Можно вызвать нашу swap так :

```
int main (){
int x = 5;
int y = 12;

swap <double>(x, y);
return 0;
}
```

Тогда компилятор увидит, что мы хотим вызвать `void swap (doublle x, double y);`, преобразует `int x; int y в double x; double y` и вызовет `void swap (doublle x, double y);` Но явно тип шаблонного параметра в случае с функциями указывают редко.

Теперь рассмотрим шаблон класса (и вспомним, что std::vector тоже шаблонный класс)

```
template <typename T>
class myArray {
// Поля класса
private :

int m_length;
T* m_data;

// Конструкторы класса

public:
    Array()
    {
        m_length = 0;
        m_data = nullptr;
    }
  Array(int length)
    {
        m_data = new T[length];
        m_length = length;
    }
 
    ~Array()
    {
        delete[] m_data;
    }
 
    void Erase()
    {
        delete[] m_data;
        // Присваиваем значение nullptr для m_data, чтобы на выходе не получить висячий указатель!
        m_data = nullptr;
        m_length = 0;
    }
 
 
    T& operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(index >= 0 && index < m_length);
        return m_data[index];
    }
 
    // Длина массива всегда является целочисленным значением, она не зависит от типа элементов массива
    int getLength(); // определяем метод и шаблон метода getLength() ниже
};
 
template <typename T> // метод, определенный вне тела класса, нуждается в собственном определении шаблона метода
int Array<T>::getLength() { return m_length; }  
}
```

Теперь мы можем написать:

```
int main()
{
    Array<int> intArray(10);
    Array<double> doubleArray(10);
 
    for (int count = 0; count < intArray.getLength(); ++count)
    {
        intArray[count] = count;
        doubleArray[count] = count + 0.5;
    }
 
    for (int count = intArray.getLength()-1; count >= 0; --count)
        std::cout << intArray[count] << "\t" << doubleArray[count] << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

Зачем мы явно указывали тип тут?

```
Array<int> intArray(10);
Array<double> doubleArray(10);
```

и почему не можем написать

```
Array array (20);
```

Потому что на выделение памяти через new (malloc, calloc)

```
Array(int length)
    {
        m_data = new T[length];
        m_length = length;
    }
```

Эта самая сложная система шаблонного вывода не рассчитана и может работать только с примитивами. Компилятор не может сам определить массив какого типа мы хотим получить и поэтому в сообщении

> [Error] 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class Array' used without
> template arguments

Просит нас явно указать тип.

С вектором то же самое.

Comment: Существуют не только шаблоны функций и классов

Answer (score 2):

Ну как я понимаю вектор-то содержит элементы какого-то типа и вы должны указать, что это за тип:

Вектор строк:

```
vector<string> arr1;
```

Вектор целых чисел

```
vector<int> arr2;
```

Вектор векторов букв

```
vector<vector<char>> arr3;
```

Шаблоны - это такие конструкции, в которых не определены типы. (например, если у вас класс для `int` и для `float` делает ровно одно и то же, то зачем вам дублировать код? Вы пишите один код на несколько типов.)

Comment: То есть в моём примере я задаю вектор с векторами (vector::vector) размера n (syze_type n), который должен содержать строки (val = string), но в случае, если пользователь введёт другой тип данных, он всё равно преобразуется к строкам (const string&), верно?

Comment: Но я всё равно не понимаю почему тут замешано template

Comment: @Ram Rai, скажите в чем именно заключается ваша задача? `vector::vector` - это просто конструктор это не вектор векторов, т.е. есть класс `vector` внутри которого есть конструктор `vector`

Comment: спасибо, поняла про конструктор теперь! Задача пока - задать вектор, но с неизвестным размером. Потом найти его размер и упорядочить элементы. Ну дальше там уже другая задача, это неважно.

Comment: @Ram Rai, вы можете создать пустой вектор - у него размер будет 0, затем добавить элементы через метод `push_back` (например, запрашивая у пользователя) (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), затем узнать размер через метод `size`, а затем отсортировать через функцию `sort` - это в библиотеке `algorithm` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Answer (score 1):

Вектор (простыми словами) можно представить как динамический массив. Когда вы определяете массив, вы присваиваете ему тип данных. Например

```cpp
int* array = new int[128];
```

А теперь вы пытаетесь создать вектор, но почему то решаете, что тип данных ему не нужен.

```cpp
vector::vector(size_type n, const string& val = string());
```

Это просто конструктор класса, без заполнения шаблона его создать не получится.

---

Вектору тип данных присваивается через шаблон:

```cpp
// Определение вектора из заголовочного файла vector
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp> >
    class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
```

В качестве первого аргумента передаётся тип данных, который должен хранить вектор. Вторым аргументом распределитель памяти (если второго аргумента нет - используется распределитель по умолчанию).

---

Например, создадим вектор целых чисел с размером в 10 ячеек:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec(10);
```

Вы можете по необходимости менять его размер с помощью функции `resize`. Но не забывайте, что перераспределение памяти это дорогостоящая в плане времени выполнения операция, и если количество элементов известно заранее лучше сделать вектор сразу нужно размера (или использовать `vector::reserve`)

---

Вы также можете передавать в конструктор значение, которым должен быть инициализирован только что созданный вектор.

Например:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec(10, 2);
```

создаст вектор из 10 элементов, заполненный двойками.

---

Я здесь рассказал только самое начало, если интересно подробнее:
[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)